# Can 1 Corinthians 6:12 and 10:23 be translated as hyperbole?

Tags: greek

> **1 Timothy 6:10**:
> the root of all evil        (KJV)
> a root of all kinds of evil (NKJV)

The changed interpretation in the New KJV is similar to most other translations, a hyperbolic expression meaning "most" or "many kinds" rather than the literal "all".

In Acts, Paul also uses the same Greek word for "all" and the translation retains the hyperbole (not exhaustive lists):

> **5:34** reputation among all the people
> **8:40** he preached in all the cities
> **13:24** to all the people of Israel.
> **17:22** all things ye are too superstitious.
> **18:17** Then all the Greeks took
> **19:19** burned them before all men
> **20:35** I have shewed you all things
> **24:5** among all the Jews throughout the world

And in other cases the hyperbole itself is translated into non-hyperbolic language:

> **5:11** upon as many as heard these things
> **13:44** almost the whole city

And of course there are many more cases where it *does* have a literal meaning.

---

The question is about 1 Corinthians:

> **6:12** All things are lawful
> **10:23** All things are lawful

Would it be reasonable to translate this expression as hyperbolic for "all kinds of things", or "many kinds of things", or "many things"?

E.g.

> All kinds of things are lawful for me, but not all things are expedient:
> Many things are lawful for me, but not all things edify.

Comment: There are several questions on this theme on this site.  Essentially, the "pan" = "all" means "all in an implied class of things".  In the above cases, the "all" is rather easy to determine - all people are those involved, etc.  Thus, it is not hyperbole.

Comment: @Dottard, the examples I gave are clearly hyperbole. Are you saying they are *all* literal, including "all evil"?  If not, I'm asking what is it that allows "all evil" to be considered hyperbolic but doesn't allow "all things" to be hyperbolic?

Comment: @Dottard, says '*"all" means "all in an implied class of things"*", and similarly "all things are lawful" can thus mean "all things in the class of things that are lawful". I'm asking what is it about "all evil" that allowed the KJ translators to translate it differently that wouldn't also allow them to translate "all things"  differently?

Comment: A general statement, not a hyperbole

Comment: @Michael16, an appositive noun phrase, not a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no support in the Greek text of 1 Corinthians 6:12 & 10:23 for including "sorts of", anybody translating such additions to the text would need to put [sorts of] - in square brackets, denoting an addition.

Even in dynamic-equivalence modern translations (such as the N.L.T.) there is no sense of Paul really meaning, "all kinds of things". He makes the point to libertines in the Church who claim, "I am allowed to do anything", that "not everything is good for you". But that is within the context of doing things in the body. Paul is dealing with Antinomianism, the idea that there is now no law against Christians doing things that were forbidden in God's law. The N.L.T. goes on to suggest that Paul is really saying, "And even though 'I am allowed to do anything', I must not become a slave to anything." It's the same way of putting the matter in 10:23 (which is basically a repetition, as Paul is concluding his argument).

Yes, Paul lists the sorts of things he speaks of in 6:9-10, so there is nothing wrong in having that list in mind (which might only be partial, or a summary of the most offensive things) when coming to 6:12 and 10:23. He has given examples of the things. There could, therefore, be scope for putting ***"all [those kinds of] things..."*** **in dynamic equivalence translations but, again, the added words that are not in the Greek text would have to have square brackets around them.**

Now, this is where 1 Timothy 6:10 comes in, but perhaps not in the way suggested by the OP. In literal, formal-equivalence translations, they stick to the Greek text that simply says (in literal word-for-word English under the Greek):

> "For a root of all evils is the love of money" *The Englishman's Greek
> New Testament*, Robert Estienne, 1550, and also *The Interlinear
> Greek-English New Testament*, Alfred Marshall, 1958

There is a footnote in Marshall's literal translation of 1 Tim.6:10 that says,

> " * For order of words see note on John 1:1." [that note saying]:
>
> - But note that the subject has the article and the predicate has it not; hence translate - "the Word was God".

This pertains to 1 Timothy 6:10, "For a root..." in the Greek, and may explain why the A.V. has "the root of all evil" while the N.K.J. and other translations have "a root of all kinds of evil". Of interest is that the 1898 translation by Robert Young has, "For a root of all the evils".

I can say nothing about this, for it only came to my attention just now while preparing this answer regarding 1 Corinthians. As the OP brought in 1 Timothy, that is when I noticed the footnote in Marshall's Interlinear, and I just mention it in case the real issue that needs thrashing out might be *"the subject has the article and the predicate has it not"*. Is the real issue about "a", and not "all"? Perhaps someone could frame a new question about that?

**Back to the question about 1 Corinthians:** Given that hyperbole is "exaggerated statements, not meant to be taken literally" - ***the answer*** I offer is that Paul meant his statement to be taken literally, even though he had particular things in mind (as in earlier verses). **In the sense of "All those things I am writing to you about", it is meant to be taken literally.**

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how "hyperbole" is defined. But first, we need to be aware of what is being talked about in this verse. The sentence begins:

> For the love of money is the root of all evils...

The author clearly knew the story of Adam and Eve and there was no money in the Garden. So I would reject the proposition that he intended to say that the love of money was literally the root of all evils.

Would it be reasonable to translate the verse as "all kinds of things," etc.? I would say *yes* to reasonable but *no* to preferable. It is better to handle these kinds of nuances in footnotes. But the verse itself is clearly teaching something false if it is taken literally.

**So yes, the statement can be taken as a hyperbole if the term is defined as "a purposeful exaggeration not meant to be taken literally." But if it is defined as an [extravagant exaggeration (such as "mile-high ice-cream cone")](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperbole) then the answer would be no.**